# Failed to connect to localhost port 9515 after 0 ms: Connection refused

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-dusk

I work on Manjaro, if is import. So I install dusk and chrome-driver from docs:

```
sail composer require --dev laravel/dusk
sail artisan dusk:install
sail artisan dusk:chrome-driver
```

Of course I have Chrome browser (currently Chromium too). I tryed restart Chrope becouse I found this tips in the Internet. All the time I have this error:
[image]
I installed Chromium becouse I had a problem with dusk but nothing change. Where is problem?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have selenium defined in your docker-compose.yml. If not, follow documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sail#laravel-dusk

Also you need to run "sail dusk" instead of "sail artisan dusk".